# scaling table for mobile web app

Tags: php, css, web-applications

I am trying to scale my table in PHP for a mobile web app, and i have quite a lot of fields echoed out.

Is there a neat way to style these as they are too far right at the minute

```
echo "<table cellspacing=\"0\" class=\"recordsTableBG\"> <thead class=\"recordsTableHeader\" >";
echo '<tr class="alternateRowColor">';
echo '<tr><th>id</th><th>amount</th><th>submission</th><th>project_id</th><th>status</th><th>description</th><th>delete</th></tr></thead>';
  //echo "<form method='post' action=\"pmsystem.php?page=sentbox\">".
           echo "<form method='post' action=\"viewrecordsemp1.php\">".
            "    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"deleteMessage\" value=\"yes\">".
            "    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=\"$id\">".
            "<td><b>$id </b> <br></td>".
            "<td>$amount</a><br/></td>".
            "<td>$submission</a><br/></td>".
            "<td>$project_id</a><br/></td>".
            "<td>$status</a><br/></td>".
            "<td>$description</a><br/></td>".
            "    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"thisPage\" value=\"$thisPage\">".           
            "   <td> <input type=\"image\" src=\"images/delete.jpg\" alt=\"Delete contact\" onClick = \"return confirm('$first_name are you sure you want to delete this message?')\";></td>".
            "    </form>";

            echo "</table>";
            echo "<hr = '1'>";
```

Comment: clearly coded by a js developer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what data is in these fields, but you could echo maybe the 3 most essential columns and have the rest of the data put into an invisible `<div>` that takes up the screen.  The `<div>` is unhidden when the entry is clicked and all the options are neatly displayed.  This would mean you would have to have a separate set of PHP code to run on mobile, you have to keep the table format pretty much the same if you want to just do a mobile stylesheet.

But keep in mind that many mobile phone users use the phone horizontally to browse the web on non-mobile-specific sites.  Unless your site is specifically designed for mobile or the text still goes offscreen in horizontal view, consider leaving it the way it is unless people are complaining.

Comment: i am developing a mobile web app and tailoring it to a mobile device screen